# Get Size, location and name of each shared folder

Tags: windows, powershell, size, shared

I have this code that generates a list of all the shares and the size however can not generate a txt with this information or the shared location

```
$servers = @("servername")
$sizes = @()
foreach($server in $servers) {
write-host "Server: $server"
(gwmi -class Win32_Share -ComputerName $server -filter "Type = 0" | 
% { 
  write-host " share: $($_.Name)"
  $s = gci \\$server\$($_.Name) -recurse -force | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum
  New-Object PSObject -property @{Name=$_.Name; Server=$server;  TotalSize=$s.Sum } 
 }) 

}
```

And this not only shows me the size and generates txt size and can generate txt

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_share -computer server01    | FT "server01", path, name  > ServerShares.txt
Get-WmiObject Win32_share -computer server02    | FT "server02", path, name >> ServerShares.txt
```

Someone could help me to create only one that does everything

Comment: Never use write host or a formatting (ft, fl etc) if you plan to output to a file (it causes layout problems, cut off text). You can use select-object and pipe that to out-file (or even export-csv or first do a convert to html for a nice layout)

Answer (score 1):

In your `New-Object` you just need to add additional properties to get the information you want:

*If you're not running PowerShell v3, remove `[Ordered]`*

```
$servers = @("servername")
$sizes = @()

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    write-host "Server: $server"

    # Get all shares
    $shares = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -ComputerName $server -filter "Type = 0"

    # go through each share
    foreach($share in $shares)
    { 
        write-host " share: $($share.Name)"

        # Get size of share
        $size = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$server\$($_.Name)" -recurse -force | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum

        # Create a new object to store information
        New-Object PSObject -property ([ordered]@{
            # Name of share
            Name = $share.Name

            # Share path
            Path = $share.path

            # What server share is on
            Server = $server

            # Total size of share
            TotalSize = $size.Sum

            # Change this path to where you want the file to be saved to
        }) | Export-Csv -Path C:\ShareDetails.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    } 
}
```

Comment: The code can not access the shares, I use a V4


    Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\c' because it does not exist.
At line:17 char:17
+         $size = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$server\$($_.Name) -recurse -force | Measu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\c:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: What is `$server` set to? If `c` was a share it should have checked `\\server01\c` instead of `\\c`.

Also try putting the `Get-ChildItem` path parameter in quotes like `"\\$server\$($_.Name)"`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small revision to @Bluecakes response in order to use COM instead of .NET to capture the size information. This overcomes the path-length issues.

```
    # Get size of share
    # $size = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($share.Name)" -recurse -force | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum
    $objFSO = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject 
    $size = "{0:N2}" -f (($objFSO.GetFolder("$($share.Name)").Size) / 1MB)
```

Then you also need to remove ".sum"

```
     # Total size of share
     TotalSize = $size
```